# Unable to solve expression for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve this expression for $x$:

$$\frac{x^n(n(1-x)+1)}{(1-x)^2}=0$$

I'm not sure where to begin (especially getting rid of the $x^n$ part), any hints or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Try multiplying both sides by the denominator, to get rid of it. Note that this may introduce [extraneous solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) if what we multiplied by is $0$, so you have to consider the case of $(x - 1)^2 = 0$ separately.

Finally, to solve an equation of the form $a \cdot b = 0$, you can divide by $a \neq 0$ on both sides to get $b = 0$, but this may lead to missing solutions if $a = 0$ is also a solution. So again, consider the cases $a = 0$ and $a \neq 0$ (and therefore $b = 0$) separately.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x^n*(n(1-x)+1)}{(1-x)^2} = 0$ is equivalent to $x^n*(n(1-x)+1) = 0$ and $x \neq 1$.

But $x^n*(n(1-x)+1) = 0$ is equivalent to $x = 0$ or $n(1-x) + 1 = 0$, e.g. $x=0$ or $1+\frac{1}{n}$.

Finally, the solutions are $$x \in \{0, 1 + \frac{1}{n}\}$$

Comment: Just to get back to you, some of us refer to another user (when the username is ambiguous as to gender) as s/he, and others sometimes use "they" as a generic reference (which even though it may not be grammatically correct when referring to a singular person, is becoming common usage). E.g. "They can read every other word, if they want..." Also, please don't think I downvoted your correct answer! I rarely downvote ;-)

Comment: Thank you for these details !

Comment: You're welcome!! ;-)